# Dynamically populated select box overlapped by neighboring div element in IE 7

Tags: javascript, css, layout, internet-explorer-7

I have some legacy JavaScript code that dynamically populates a Select Box. In Firefox, it looks fine. In IE7, the layout is wrong (see below). If I re-size the window, it re-renders  the select box properly.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like before re-sizing the browser window.

[image: IE7 SUCKS]

Here is the code complete source code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Test </title>
 </head>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var MyOptions = {
    "A" : "Option 1 (A)",
    "B" : "Option 2 (B)",
    "C" : "Option 3 (C)",
    "D" : "Option 4 (D)"
}

var MyForm = {

    loadSelectBox : function () {

        dropDown=document.getElementById("my_select_box");

        while(dropDown.hasChildNodes()) {
            dropDown.removeChild(dropDown.lastChild);
        }

        var firstOption = document.createElement('option');
        firstOption.value = '';
        firstOption.innerHTML = 'select a filter';
        dropDown.appendChild(firstOption);

        for (var key in MyOptions) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = key;
            option.innerHTML = MyOptions[key];
            dropDown.appendChild(option);
        }

    }
}

function init() {
    MyForm.loadSelectBox();
} //-->
</script>

<body onload="init();">
    <div style="margin:0px 10px 0px 10px; width:98%">
        <div style="float:left;">  
            <select id="my_select_box">
                <!-- options go here -->
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:25px;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="is-foo" style="visibility:visible;">
            <label for="is-foo" style="visibility:visible;">Some label</label>
            <input type="button" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br class="clear"/>
</body>
</html>
```

What could I do to make this layout properly in IE7?  I need the select box to populate dynamically (this is a dumbed-down version of the code; the actual application is obtaining the values from a web service).

I tried intializing the select box with a long value (which the JavaScript will discard), i.e.

```
<select id="my_select_box">
    <option name="">Really long value that will be removed but is here for padding.</option>
</select>
```

However, this still doesn't look right and feels like a hack. Is there some css that will make the two `<div>` elements layout nicely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force repaint of element after your list is populated:

```
document.getElementById('repaintMe').style.zoom = 1;
```

However this might cause page flickering (depending on layout), so you probably should combine it with min-width rules or apply different wrapper eg. table. Example for repaint here http://cdpn.io/ubiva

Comment: Flickering is a small price to pay for form usability. Thanks!  Also, this: http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#hasLayout Apparently just adding `style.zoom = 1` fixes all sorts of IE issues. Crazy!